# Can polyline animation be applied to open street map?

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I was wondering if Polyline can be animated in open street map. I looked but couldn't find anything satisfactory.

I am talking about something like this site http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip2.htm

Here the route is drawn between two points. I want animation for a polyline that is just a line between two points.(Not a route)

Can this be done? If so how?

Comment: Take a look at Leaflet or OpenLayers.

Comment: What exactly should i be looking for there?